# Dynamic filename not working (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that I need to reference in a macro. It always has today's date in the filename. I am able to open it perfectly with the following script:

```
'Open today's PHO report
Workbooks.Open FileName:="\\netapp02\ProcurementDocs$\PHO\PHO " & TodaysDate & ".xlsx"
```

But, I also want to reference this workbook for an array in a VLOOKUP formula. I can't get it to work! I've tried using the INDIRECT command, but it didn't seem to work. Please advise. Here's the code. How do I get the proper value for RefFile, and how do I code the IFNA/VLOOKUP?

```
'VLOOKUP against PHO report and return Key match or the word "No"
Range("Z2").Formula = "=IFNA(VLOOKUP(Y2,""'["" & RefFile & ""]'!$C:$D"",1,0),""NO"")"
```

Thanks.

Karl

Comment: When you save and reopen does it retain your formula with the proper network path?

Comment: if you were to enter the formula manually then what do you actually type in the cell. Also once you have entered the formula, close the network file and then see what the formula has turned into. If possible, can you post that formula here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly assume that `RefFile` is a variable in your VBA code. At the moment, you hardcode
 `& RefFile &` into the formula, but not its content.

Change this

```
Range("Z2").Formula = "=IFNA(VLOOKUP(Y2,""'["" & RefFile & ""]'!...
```

into this:

```
Range("Z2").Formula = "=IFNA(VLOOKUP(Y2,""'[""" & RefFile & """]'!...
```

Comment: Yep. I was missing a quote. Thanks!